# Does Resharper support RowTest?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, rowtest

Resharper doesn't recognise Rowtests, is this normal? Is there anyway to fix it? (*other than splitting rowtest manually*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install Gallio www.gallio.org

it has a ReSharper plugin that lets you run NUnit/MbUnit row tests

Comment: Thanks, Last time I've used Gallio was terribly slow and a bit unstable, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: it's gone a long way since then. although it is still far from perfect ;)